# Why we need serialization using JSON in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm new with MVC and json objects, I'm trying to understand why in some pages (or always don't know...) we need to serialize or deserialize objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really short answer is: **because interoperability**. Your browser may be implemented in a different programming language and would not know how to interpret your "un-serialized" object. Furthermore, finding out how an object is built, without knowing its type/structure, is a difficult task even in the same programming language. The best example is a custom class--a model, if you will-- that you build in your MVC project. It can be as simple or as complicated as needed, but the browser by itself will still not be able to parse it.

The short answer is: **because everybody understands strings**. If you pass along strings and agree upon a specific structure, you're basically creating a mini-programing language. It's just mark-up that everybody can read and write, independent from location or programming platform.

Since you have only two structures, a JSON string is also easy to parse. You just have a succession of objects `{}` and arrays `[]`. An additional advantage is that it does represent the objects with a minimum number of characters, which translates to a shorter send time.

A short conclusion, use JSON to send objects (like class instances) to your views or, even better, when you use AJAX to communicate between the browser and the server (i.e. get a confirmation message for an insert/update/delete).

Comment: Or: because XML is too mainstream.

Comment: In Xml you still need to know the structure. Another disadvantage is that Xml requires additional bytes for formating the data. Xml is more expressive though...